# ¿Como exporto/migro un Wordpress de Cloudways hacia Siteground?

Tags: wordpress

tengo un problema al exportar mi sitio de Cloudways a un servidor externo, he usado plugins como (All-in-one wp / duplicator / siteground migrator) pero todos me dan errores o bugs al migrar, el plugin de siteground migrator lo bloquea y no deja ingresar el token.

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

qué procedimiento estás siguiendo para migrar tu WordPress?, utilizando All-in-one WP, como tiene limitaciones, el procedimiento que suelo hacer es el siguiente:

1. Respaldar solo base de datos con All-in-one WP.
2. Descargar la carpeta WP Content de tu sitio por FTP.
3. Instalar WP en tu nuevo host.
4. Subir la carpeta WP Content al nuevo host.
5. Instalar All-in-one WP en el nuevo sitio
6. Realizar el proceso de importación de base de datos.

Otros plugins que me han resultado efectivo para migrar:

Backup Bliss
https://backupbliss.com/

Lo puedes encontrar como `Backup Migration`, aunque la migración de archivos es una feature premium.

WP Clone by WP Academy
https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/

Este es muy sencillo de utilizar y migra todo brindándote un link que puedes copiar y pegar en el host destino y se encarga del proceso.

Por otro lado, puedes hacer este proceso sin ningún plugin siguiendo los pasos anteriores, pero importando la base de datos directamente y ejecutando un query en PHP my admin para corregir cualquier URL o IP que no apunte a tu nuevo host, este proceso es un poco más complejo pero también efectivo.

He migrado varios sitios y cada uno es especial, principalmente por las diferencias de tamaño de los sitios y limitaciones del proveedor de hosting, quedo atento si estas recomendaciones no te funcionan para brindarte algunas más que podrían funcionar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, la verdad he utilizado all-in-one-wp nulled (si entiendo que esta mal) pero primero es para un servidor de prueba y al exportar bugea la pagina, tambien hice en bruto (pasando los archivos por ftp y subiendo la base.sql ) aunque si podria decirme el query para corregir las urls/ip te lo agradeceria, voy a intentar probar tu solución, gracias (:

Comment: Seguro @Oren! El query a ejecutar para cambiar la URL BASE del sitio, sería algo así: 

`UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'dominioanterior.old', 'dominionuevo.new') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'dominioanterior.old','dominionuevo.new');UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'dominioanterior.old', 'dominionuevo.new'); UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'dominioanterior.old','dominionuevo.new');` 

Tener en cuenta el prefijo de las tablas (wp_)

Comment: Lo puedes ejecutar desde PHP My Admin, me avisas en cualquier caso!

Comment: Amigo, te debo una, me funciono el plugin de Clone, había intentado de todo, igual las otras opciones también las probare, muchisimas gracias exitos!

Comment: Cuánto me alegro Oren!, siempre a la orden, un saludo!